# android honeycomb - how to recognize that keyboard has been switched to symbols/numeric mode?

Tags: android, input, keyboard, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is it possible to recognize that the keyboard has been switched from alpha to symbols/numeric mode and respond to this action? How?

Thanks  in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to recognize that the keyboard has been switched from alpha to symbols/numeric mode and respond to this action?

No, sorry. Your application should neither know nor care whether the input method editor is set up to respond to taps that generate letters, taps that generate numbers, taps that generate symbols, handwriting recognition for any character, etc.

Comment: can I make a switch programmatically?

Comment: @Asahi: No. You have no idea if the keyboard even has such a switch.